# Add value to "Other" property in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, insert-update, multiple-value

Some fields in AD have a option "other" for multiple values:
[AD fields screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwcM3.png)

I tried to add new values to this field using following code:

```
 if (Domaincontact.Telephones.Faxes != null)
   {
     foreach (var fax in Domaincontact.Telephones.Faxes)
       {
        if(activeDirectoryContact.Properties[FAX].Contains(fax)) continue;
            activeDirectoryContact.Properties[FAX].Add(fax);
        }
    }
 activeDirectoryContact.CommitChanges();
```

But after last line of code have an exception:

```
ExtendedErrorMessage = "00002081: AtrErr: DSID-031517FA, #2:\n\t0: 00002081: DSID-031517FA, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 17 (facsimileTelephoneNumber)\n\t1: 00002081: DSID-031517FA, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 17 (facsimileTelephoneNumber)\n"
```

Whats wrong with AD? ;D Can someone advice me what I missing?

Comment: FAX in this example `FAX = "facsimileTelephoneNumber"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured out by myself. Here the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9htwgRGRdygUTUzMGpsbVMtdU0/view) to AD fields description. In my scenario it would be:

`otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber`

and other:

`otherHomePhone
otherIpPhone
otherLoginWorkstations
otherMailbox
otherMobile
otherPager
otherTelephone`